# Token Method on Forms, Double Submit Issue

Tags: php, forms

I've spent weeks working on double-submit protection on my forms.  Straightup, the session method of storing tokens doesn't work.

Sessions work fine for a refresh of the page or someone going back through their history... but the classic double submit by clicking the button numerous times cannot be prevented using sessions.

I'm thinking the script cannot check/write/delete sessions fast enough to catch the error when multiple clicks are being processed within milliseconds of each other.

Is there another server side method to preventing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need an independant token store capable of avoiding race conditions. To get this to work several solutions are available, one of the easier to implement would be:

- Store the token in a database, with (tokencode,claimid) fields.
- On receiving, set a claimid to `microtime()`, possibly even a process-id, or hash, as long as it's very much assured to be unique in similar processes started within moment from each other.
- Try to claim the token: `UPDATE tokens SET claimid = <id> WHERE tokencode=tokencode AND claimid IS NULL`
- Count rows changed of previous statement (or do a select).
- If a row has changed and/or has your microtime()'d claimid: you are the winner, continue with the action
- If nothing has changed or the token has the wrong claimid the action will not be taken.

Comment: You sir, are good.  This seems to be working.  I reinstated the token checking in my forms class, but used database instead of sessions.  I'm doing a slight variant of what you suggested -- table with id/token/used, insert row with unique token and used=false on form start, check if row used on submit, and update row with used=true on finish.

Comment: Your alteration removes a lot of effort from the atomicity: do not wait to set used to true, and claim it with a unique id. In the 5ms between your check & setting it to true about 10 other processes may have come along. Granted, less chance then a whole session write/load, but still.

Comment: I appreciate this difference and have made the change.  Thanks much for your help.