# duplicate data insert in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, duplicate-data, double-submit-prevention

I am just inserting data in codeigniter controller part at pastebin http://pastebin.com/KBtqrAkZ

```
  public function add_product()
  {
    $this->lang->load('log_in', 'english');
        log_in_check($this->lang->line('log_in_authentication_error'), 'admin/log_in');
        $this->lang->load('common', 'english');
        $data['title'] = $this->lang->line('admin_index_title');
        $this->load->view('admin_template/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin_template/left_menu');
    $data['error_msg'] = '';
        if ($this->form_validation->run('add_product') === TRUE)
        {
      $this->admin_model->add_product($this->input->post());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status_msg', $this->lang->line('add_product_success'));
            redirect(uri_string(), 'refresh');
      exit ;
          $data['error_msg'] = $this->lang->line('add_product_invalid_data');
        }
        $this->load->view('admin/add_product');
        //$this->load->view('admin_template/notification');
        $this->load->view('admin_template/footer');  
  }
```

Than my model part is simple add at pastebin http://pastebin.com/WiLHV2sr

```
  public function add_product($data = array())
  {
    $this->db->insert('ishop_product', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
  }
```

my problem is after redirecting if I press ctrl + F5 or F5 than the data is inserting. I am a new in codeigniter. Help me please. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699352/solving-the-double-submission-problem

Comment: And this one has a good answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313582/token-method-on-forms-double-submit-issue

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the **Double Submit Problem**.

There are several ways of dealing with it:

1. **[The Post / Redirect / Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)**: Breaks the back button, and it does not keep your user from going back far enough to submit again. Does not handle multiple clicks.
2. **Disable the submit button**: Handles multiple clicks some of the time, but does not fix the user going back and submitting again.
3. **[Store a token in the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699352/solving-the-double-submission-problem)**: If you have multiple tabs open in the browser, the token stored in the session may get mixed up. (Note: It may be possible to [create browser tab specific cookies](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/878108-creating-browser-tab-specific-cookie) using javascript, but I have not tried it myself.)
4. **Change the database to not allow duplicates**: The best solution, but also the most effort. If it detects a set of duplicate data, ignore the second request.
5. **Unique transaction id**: Described on this [PHP hacks page](http://www.freeopenbook.com/php-hacks/phphks-CHP-6-SECT-6.html), and on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313582/token-method-on-forms-double-submit-issue).
6. **Multiple tokens in the session**: A variation on option 3. If you store all generated tokens in the session, you don't need to involve the database. The probability of a duplicate is much lower, given that tokens are unique inside a session. Possible problems include the set of tokens growing out of control. Maybe fixable with a limited size stack where you add to the top of the stack, and extra tokens fall off the bottom. Untested.

--

I like the **unique transaction id** method. It works like this:

1. Generate a random `transaction_id` and put it in your web form. It goes along when the user clicks `submit`.
2. When you receive the request to add a product, **check** for the `transaction_id` in the transaction table.
3. If the id *does not exist* in the table, do the transaction, and insert the transaction_id into the table.
4. If the id *does exist* in the table, the transaction is already done.

You should also search for [[double-submit-prevention]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-submit-prevention) in to see if you can find an even better solution.

Comment: This might actually *be* the best PHP related answer specifically tagged [double-submit-prevention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-submit-prevention) simply for it's broadness (and that there are fairly few questions with the tag). Personally, I never liked PRG verbatim, as described on Wikipedia. Being able to for instance, bookmark or send a link to a "success" page just seems wrong.

Comment: By the time future readers end up here, better solutions may exist. Like say, multiple tokens in the session. Actually... that might work. Hmm.

Answer (score 2):

Theres a simple solution, you can redirect to some other page after adding product, like:

```
redirect(base_url(). "yourcontrollername/index");
```

Doing this will remove the post data and data would not be re-added to database.

Comment: I have changed `redirect(uri_string(), 'refresh');` to `redirect(uri_string());` and it has been solved I could have taken your ans but it isn't optimized.