# Data inserted three times CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$data = array(
    'date' => $time,
    'boxoffice'=> $boxoffice,
    'upcoming'=> $upcoming,
    'intheaters'=> $intheaters,
    'opening' => $opening,
    'user'  => $users,
    'movie' => $movies,
    'star'  => $actors,
    'diractor' => $directores,
    'writer'  => $writeres,
    'cast'  => $casts,
    'comment'=> $comment,
    'image' => $images,
    'genre' => $genre,
    'country'=> $countrycode
);

try {
    $this->db->insert('muvidb_updatehistory',$data);
}
catch (Exception $e){}
```

I have those codes above in my project, at first it seems working fine but when i looked into my table, the value inserted three times. I’m new in codeigniter and i am stuck with this problem.

Anyone have an idea why is this happening?

Comment: Something is off, theres something you're not showing us. That code would never be called 3 times.

Comment: is that happening when you reload the page..?

Comment: Jan is right, that couldn't insert three times just from that code. Could you share a little more with us? Also, you might want to add some more indexes to your table in your db to avoid this problem both sides.

Comment: original url is http://www.muvidb.com/index.php/updatedb/history/

Comment: When i load the page . it should insert into db

Comment: function history(<passing value>){
  
  $data=array(
   'date'    =>$time,
   'boxoffice'  => $boxoffice,
   'upcoming'   => $upcoming,
   'intheaters' => $intheaters,
   'opening'   => $opening,
   'user'    => $users,
   'movie'   => $movies,
   'star'    => $actors,
   'diractor'   => $directores,
   'writer'    => $writeres,
   'cast'    => $casts,
   'comment'  => $comment,
   'image'   => $images,
   'genre'   => $genre,
   'country'    => $countrycode
  );
  try {
   
   $this->db->insert('muvidb_updatehistory',$data);
  }
  catch (Exception $e){}
 }

Comment: "NOTHING IS OFF " well, evidently, something IS off, otherwise it wouldn't be inserting the record into the db 3 times.

Comment: who,when and how calls that function history?

Comment: Flukey : just ref this url :http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/204526/ and tel What happed in this ????

Comment: @Gianps : each day it will call by cron job

Comment: can u let u see the full code in that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked to see if you have some sort of rewrite trickery or a dev debug tool that would access that URL 3 times? (Or even a referrer search bot, or the like...)

This is why you should probably verify it's a POST request before inserting data.  GET requests that adhere to HTTP specs shouldn't alter data...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have poor double submit checking. More information, see my answer here: [duplicate data insert in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165018/duplicate-data-insert-in-codeigniter/8165979#8165979)

Your best bet in this case is to see if the data already exists, and if it does, to update it instead of insert. I'll add an example later.