# How to disable button after one click with validation using javascript?

Tags: javascript

First I want to validate some of the field values entered or not. After that When i click the submit button, the button must be disabled after one click to avoid duplicate submission. How to do that using javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ValidateIt() {
      if (document.getElementById('ddlProblemCategory').value == 0) {
           alert("Please fill some value");
           return false;
      }
           return true;
    }
    function DisableIt() {
        if (ValidateIt() == true)
          document.getElementById('btnSaveProblem').disabled = true;
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: If you are using jquery, google jquery validate plugin(If you don't use jquery, google javascript validation). Learn you some client side validation. Then If you face any problem with that, come here post the code & ask for help.

Comment: The following post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165018/duplicate-data-insert-in-codeigniter/8165979#8165979

Comment: Upvoted this as it is the first non-jquery result in my google

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add an `onclick` handler to your button:

```
document.getElementById("idOfButton").onclick = function() {
    //disable
    this.disabled = true;

    //do some validation stuff
}
```

Comment: In my particular case I was able to just put the onclick right into the input

`<input type="button" id="btnFinish" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Finish" onclick="this.disabled = true" />`

Answer (score 5):

Call function `submitbtn` onclick of the button.

Use

```
function submitbtn() {
    getElementById("Submit_id").disabled=true;
   // Validation code goes here
}
```

Comment: You have missed 'd' in `disabled`...It should be `getElementById("Submit_id").disabled=true;`

Comment: @VigneshVino thanks buddy.. changed as per u..

Comment: It should be 
`document.getElementById("Submit_id").disabled=true;`
You missed the DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden label and change its value on 1st click

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    function disableButton() {
        var lblText = document.getElementById('lbl_hdn_text').innerHTML;
        if (lblText == "true") {
            document.getElementById('lbl_hdn_text').innerHTML = "false";
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<label id="lbl_hdn_text"  style = "display:none;" >true</label>
```