# How to make a button clickable once?

Tags: javascript, html, button, click

In my code I want a button to be clickable once. I put 2 buttons below me because I want to disable the other button for use when one of the buttons are clicked.

```
<div style = "position:absolute; left:625px; top:100px; background-color:white;">
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('The guy walks away disapointed, I think I made the wrong decision')" >Detain</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('The guy sighs in relief and looked happy. The guards guide him to the exit. I think I made the right decision')">Free them</button>
         </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vanilla Javascript : how to make a button clickable once only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63122118/vanilla-javascript-how-to-make-a-button-clickable-once-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give every button a unique id then disable the other button on the click like in the following example

```
    <div style = "position:absolute; left:625px; top:100px; background-  color:white;">
<button id="btn1" type="button" onclick="alert('The guy walks away disapointed, I think I made the wrong decision'); document.getElementById('btn2').disabled = true;" >Detain</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button" onclick="alert('The guy sighs in relief and looked happy. The guards guide him to the exit. I think I made the right decision'); document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = true;">Free them</button>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude. This was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Let me check if I did understand correctly, you want a button to be disabled when the opposite one is pressed.

First I'll separate your code in 2 pieces to make it more readable, you can merge it by setting the JS part in `<script></script>` tags:

```
<script>
   //JS code here
</script>
```

```js
let detainButton = document.getElementById('detainButton');
let freeButton = document.getElementById('freeButton');

function handleDetain() {
  alert('The guy walks away disappointed. I think I made the wrong decision');
  detainButton.disabled = true;
  freeButton.disabled = false;
}

function handleFree() {
  alert('The guy sighs in relief and looks happy. The guards guide him to the exit. I think I made the right decision');
  freeButton.disabled = true;
  detainButton.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 625px; top: 100px; background-color: white;">
    <button type="button" onclick="handleDetain()" id="detainButton">Detain</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="handleFree()" id="freeButton">Free them</button>
</div>
```

Instead of setting the alerts into the buttons, now you'll have 2 separate functions containing the alerts and switching the `disabled` state of the button depending on the opposite one.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use `this.disabled='true';`
I'd recommend you this code.

```
      style="
        position: absolute;
        left: 625px;
        top: 100px;
        background-color: white;
      "
    >
      <button
        type="button"
        id="btn1"
        onclick="alert('The guy walks away disapointed, I think I made the wrong decision') ; document.getElementById('btn2').disabled='true'; this.disabled='true'"
      >
        Detain
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        id="btn2"
        onclick="alert('The guy sighs in relief and looked happy. The guards guide him to the exit. I think I made the right decision'); document.getElementById('btn1').disabled='true'; this.disabled='true'"
      >
        Free them
      </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

style part(css):

```
<style>
    div{
        position:absolute;
        left:625px;
        top:100px;
        background-color:white;
    }
</style>
```

html part:

```
<div>
        <button type="button" onclick="detainButton()" id="detain-button">Detain</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="freeThemButton()" id="free-them-button">Free them</button>
</div>
```

script part(javascript):

```
<script>
    
    function detainButton(){
        alert('The guy walks away disapointed, I think I made the wrong decision');
        document.getElementById("free-them-button").disabled = true;
    }
    function freeThemButton(){
        alert('The guy sighs in relief and looked happy. The guards guide him to the exit. I think I made the right decision');
        document.getElementById("detain-button").disabled = true;
    }

</script>
```