# good hash for email address to avoid collision

Tags: php, email, hash

I've a simple contact page where the user insert only the email address, to avoid double post I thought to create a simple sqlite3 db with just one field with unique constrain to save the email hash (I don't want to keep plain email address in this db)

A [valid email max length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574698/2498790) is still 254?

(I know already about alternatives for [double post problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8165979/2498790))

My knowledge of math is limited, what would be a reasonable good hash to avoid collisions?

Comment: It's a weird solution to prevent double posting. Just disable the button after it was clicked.

Comment: @zerkms just a variant where the email hash is the *unique transaction id* itself, I know about [disabling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4473801/2498790) but the user may want to register multiple valid address

Comment: Overhead for nothing, with this solution I don't even need javascript, just a couple of php rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the sha512 hashing algorythm, as you're rather [not to expect any collisions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/are-there-any-known-collisions-for-the-sha-2-family-of-hash-functions) there, eg.:

```
$hash = hash('sha512', $myEmailAdress);
```